# Normal Operator that is not Self-Adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right", and I have a question about one of the examples he gives on page 130. Let $T$ be a linear operator on $F^2$ whose matrix (with respect to the standard basis) is $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -3 \\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$ I can see why this operator is not self-adjoint, but I can't see why it is normal. I have to find $T^*$ and show that $TT^* = T^*T$. How would you do this?

Comment: Well $T^*$ is represented by the conjugate transpose of the matrix representing $T$...

Comment: ...because the chosen basis (i.e., the standard one) for $\;T\;$  is orthonormal wrt the usual inner product, @xavierm02 .

Comment: To see it is normal: $T = 2I + S$, where $S$ is skew-symmetric/skew-hermitian. Obviously(?) skew-symmetric/skew-hermitian operators are normal too, and the identity commutes with everything.

Comment: In response to xaviermo2, let me see if I have this right: Since the basis is orthonormal, if I let $A = M(T)$ and $B$ be the conjugate transpose of $A$, then $B = M(T^*)$. Then $AB = \begin{bmatrix}13 & 0 \\ 0 & 13\end{bmatrix} = BA$. Since I fixed the basis for $V$, there is an isomorphism between the set of linear operators on $V$ and the set of 2x2 matrices with entries in $F$. So $A$ and $B$ correspond to unique linear operators on $V$. Since $A$ and $B$ commute, the linear operators they correspond to must as well. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're taking $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ wrt the usual, Euclidean inner product, then the "standard" basis is an orthonormal one there and wrt it it's very easy to find the adjoint:

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}2&\!-3\\3&\;2\end{pmatrix}\;\implies T^*=T^t=\begin{pmatrix}\;2&3\\\!-3&2\end{pmatrix}$$

And now just check that indeed $\;TT^*=T^*T\;$ ...