# Assuming $AA^*=A^*A$,then$\langle AA^*v,v\rangle=\overline{\langle AA^*v,v\rangle}$ clarification

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional space over $\mathbb{C}$, with a positive definite hermitian form $\langle ,\rangle$. Let $A:V\to V$ be a linear map. Show that the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (i) We have $AA^*=A^*A$.
>
> (ii) For all $v\in V$, $||Av||=||Av^*||$(where $||v||=\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle)}$
>
> (iii) We can write $A=B+iC$, where $B,C$ are hermitian, and $BC=CB$.

SOLUTION.
(i) implies (ii). Indeed,

$||Av||^2=\langle Av,Av\rangle=\langle v,A^*Av\rangle=\langle AA^*v,v\rangle=\overline{\langle AA^*v,v\rangle}=\langle A^*v,A^*v\rangle=||A^*v||^2$.***Solutions manual for Lang´s Linear Algebra,Rami Shakarchi***

**Questions:**

**1)** How can $\langle AA^*v,v\rangle=\overline{\langle AA^*v,v\rangle}$?

**2)** Since we assume that $AA^*=A^*A$. Is it implicit $A$ is hermitian matrix?

**3)** If A is not hermitian. Why use not use the conjugate and transpose? Like this $\langle AA^*v,v\rangle=\overline{\langle (AA^*)^tv,v\rangle}$? Is it because $AA^*=A^*A$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) $(AA^*v,v)=(A^*v,A^*x)=(v,AA^*v)=\overline{(AA^*v,v)}$. The last equality is the property of inner product $(u,v)=\overline(v,u)$.

Comment: (2) If $A=iI$, then $A^*=-iI\neq A$ and $AA^*=I=A^*A$.

Comment: To handle (iii) consider $B=\frac{A+A^*}{2}$ and $C=\frac{A-A^*}{2i}$, which is just how you would to to compute the real and imaginary parts of a complex number.

Comment: @Marja Why use the conjugate over the inner product? Is $AA^*$ assumed hermitian? And if $AA^*$  is not hermitian, Why not use the transpose as well? Property:$\langle Ca,b\rangle=\langle a,\overline{C^t}b\rangle$, assuming they belong to a vector space.

Comment: It is a property of inner product $(u,v)=\overline{(v,u)}$. You could use transpose only it you were to define what is the transpose of a linear transformation (you have linear transformations there, not matrices), then define what is the conjugate of a linear transformation, and finally prove that those two combined equal the adjoint. Too much work when you can just use the definition of adjoint and the definition of inner product.

Comment: I think you have a typo in (ii), and you meant perhaps $||A^*v||$ rather than $||Av^*||$. As Peter pointed out, $A$ is called a normal matrix. $A$ is not assumed to be hermitian, but notice that, despite that, $A^*A$ is hermitian.

Comment: To show that (ii) implies (i), you basically have from the proof of (i) implies (ii) that $(AA^*v,v) = (A^*Av,v)$ for all $v \in V$. Then by a process called polarization, this implies that $AA^* = A^*A$. Essentially, you replace $v$ by $v+w$, and then show that $(AA^*v,w) = (A^*Av,w)$ using properties of * and the hermitian inner product.

Comment: To show that (i) is equivalent to (iii), you essentially write $A$ as its hermitian part plus its skew-hermitian part and play around with the definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part **3**) Basically, yes. $AA^{*}$ is self-adjoint (Hermitian). We will use the fact that $AA^{*} = (AA^{*})^{*}$ in the computation below (first equality).

For part **1**)
\begin{equation}
 \langle AA^{*}v, v\rangle = \langle v, AA^{*}v \rangle = \overline{\langle AA^{*}v,v \rangle}.
\end{equation}
Note that the last equality follows from the identity $\langle v, w \rangle = \overline{\langle w, v \rangle}$, which is true for any inner product by definition.

For part **2**) If $AA^{*} = A^{*}A$ then $A$ is called *normal*, this is  weaker than being self-adjoint. That is, every self-adjoint matrix is normal, but not every normal matrix is self-adjoint. (For an example of a matrix that is normal but not self-adjoint see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584958/normal-operator-that-is-not-self-adjoint)).